# Set path of the radiobutton in jsp form

Tags: spring, jsp, dynamic, path, radio-button

I am using spring aplication 2.5. I have a list of the radio buttons displayed using list of the objects on the jsp. I want to set the path of the radiobuttons to its respective

```
objects in the list.
<form:form commandName = "artifact" name="formradioquest">
    <c:forEach var="questionArtifact" items="${artifact.questionGroupDetails}">
        <c:forEach var="answerOption" items="${questionArtifact.question.answerOptions}">
            <form:radiobutton path="choosenAnswers" value="${answerOption}" label="${answerOption.answerText}" cssClass="styled"/>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
    .
.
</form:form>
    public class Artifact{
        List<questionGroupDetails> questionGroupDetails;
        .
        .
    }
    public class questionGroupDetails{
        Question question;
        AnswerOption choosenAnswers;
        .
        .

    }
    public class Question{
        List<AnswerOption> answerOptions;
        .
        .

    }
```

How can I set the path variable of the radio buttons to the 'choosenAnswers' variable in QuestionGroupDetails class. Because when I use this code, it actually expects  'choosenAnswers' variable in Artifact. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `varStatus` property of the `<for:each ... />` tag to get the current loop index.

```
<c:forEach var="questionArtifact" items="${artifact.questionGroupDetails}" varStatus="row">
  <c:forEach var="answerOption" items="${questionArtifact.question.answerOptions}">
     <form:radiobutton path="choosenAnswers[${row.index}]" value="${answerOption}" label="${answerOption.answerText}" cssClass="styled"/>
   </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

The path property resolves this to `choosenAnswers.get(row.getIndex())`.

Comment: But this would again assume that choosenAnswers to be in artifact object which is my command object. I want to select 'chossenAnswers' of the respective 'questionArtifact' object so that when form is submitted I will access artifact.questionArtifact[0].getChoosenAnswers() in the controller

Comment: To test above answer I added the choosenAnswers list in the Artifact class, but that I dont want. The above answer gives exception saying 'Invalid property 'choosenAnswers[0]' of bean class [Artifact]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'choosenAnswers[0]': returned null'

Comment: Hi o-richie-nal, I got this problem solved. Actually you gave me initial push to resolve this thanks.

Comment: Solution - In the code you provided I changed the PATH variable to 'questionArtifact[${row.index}].choosenAnswers' and initialized the questionGroupDetails list in Artifact class as 'List<questionGroupDetails> questionGroupDetails = new AutoPopulatingList(Artifact.class);' This solved my problem perfectly. Now I can get the answer selected for each question in individual 'questionGroupDetails' object.  I must say in spring AutoPopulateList feature is really cool

Comment: o-richie-nal,  I cannot vote your answer.... I dont have enough reputations.. I am sorry :(